Is there a way to connect to Google Colab's resources while using another IDE?
I purchased computational units to develop an object segmentation CNN network... Long story short managing GitHub repos in Colab is awful since it doesn't have a CLI so I was wondering if it's possible to connect to a Google runtime from let's say VSCode or Eclipse.
I tried committing and pushing to a personal repo from Google Colab and the process was clumsy and slow for the very first commit. I tend to work in multiple branches to try different programming approaches and I'm not really keen in not having a CLI to navigate thru them.
